# Why is my subtheme screenshot not appearing?

Tags: theming

I have created a subtheme, and it shows up correctly on the admin/appearance page, but I can't seem to get my screenshot to appear.  It only displays the screenshot from the base theme.  I have declared the screenshot in mytheme.info, and the PNG file is sized to exactly 294 x 219.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: why does it bother you? Clear the cache perhaps, or go to parent theme and comment the line where screenshot is called, and clear the cache again. Also the browser cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sub theme by default inherit the screenshot from base theme.You can override the screen shot by simply adding screenshot of your sub theme in your sub theme directory

> The optional screenshot key tells Drupal where to find the theme's
>   thumbnail image, used on the theme selection page
>   (admin/build/themes). If this key is omitted from the .info file,
>   Drupal uses the "screenshot.png" file in the theme's directory.
>
> Use this key only if your thumbnail file is not called
>   "screenshot.png" or if you want to place it in a directory outside of
>   your theme's base directory (e.g. screenshot = images/screenshot.png).

```
screenshot = screenshot.png
```

Reference: https://drupal.org/node/171205#screenshot

Other things which may help.

1. As Jhilke comment try clearing your caches.
2. Check the screenshot file permission it should readable by web-server.

Comment: Thanks, arpitr. I had already cleared all caches, checked permissions, etc. I had my new image (important because it contains the company logo) in my subtheme directory, but it was still displaying the base theme's image, so I tried adding the "screenshot" key to the .info file. That didn't work, either, but changing the filename and the value in the .info file made the change take effect.